# R: Problem to get selector in web scraping multiple pages

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to get points for a web scraping in multiples pages, lamentably I am getting problems in selector (I used SelectorGadget but without success).

I have success for only individual web scraping

```
library(rvest)
points <- read_html("https://www.winemag.com/buying-guide/lagar-de-bezana-2014-aluvion-ensamblaje-red-cachapoal-valley/")

points %>% 
  html_node(".rating") %>%
  html_text() 

[1] "93points"
```

For multiples pages results are not real values:

```
library(rvest)

points <- lapply(paste0('https://www.winemag.com/?s=chile&search_type=all', 1:5),
                function(url){
                    url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes(".rating") %>% 
                        html_text()
                })
points

[[1]]
[1] "93 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points"

[[2]]
[1] "93 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points"

[[3]]
[1] "93 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points"

[[4]]
[1] "93 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points"

[[5]]
[1] "93 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points" "92 Points"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be working. I have changed the way urls are created:

```
library(rvest)

points <- lapply(paste0('https://www.winemag.com/?s=chile&drink_type=wine&page=', 1:5, '&search_type=all3', 1:5),
                 function(url){
                   url %>% read_html() %>% 
                     html_nodes(".rating") %>% 
                     html_text()
                 })
points
```

I would personally write it this way although it is certainly a matter of preference:

```
library(rvest)

df <- tibble(url = paste0('https://www.winemag.com/?s=chile&drink_type=wine&page=', 1:5, '&search_type=all3', 1:5)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    rating = read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes(".rating") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      list()
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(rating))
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if I can use R to get a selector?

Comment: I believe you can. In fact the function html_nodes is a selector, isn't it?

Comment: I mean an alternative to SelectorGadget

Comment: I usually don't use tools like SelectorGadget, but rather try to narrow down step by step what I get from the webpage using html_nodes function.